# How can I block users' access if the Macros weren't disabled at the moment?

Tags: vba

I have a registration form whose objective is register students with their data. When the file (.xslm) is opened, only the form is shown. The other sheets are invisible and the access is only alowed via password, after clicking on the "Data Base" buttom on the form.
The problem is: when the user open the workbook at first time, he is asked by Excel to "Enable the Content", and the students'data (registration list - Sheet1) is shown.
I have created a sheet ("Warning"), which advises the user to click on "Enable Content" as soon as he open the workbook. I just want to show this sheet when they open the file. After users clicks on "Enbale Content", the form can be shown.

Which code can I use for that? Can someone advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to force macros to run whether the end user wants them to or not. Office products prevent that  specifically to prevent malware VBA viruses from causing damage. I'm not saying your code will cause damage, but that's why it won't run without the `Enable Content` warning. If you're on a managed network, and it's not the user's personal PC, there may be a way to get IT to create a Trust Center entry to allow your code to run, or possibly get it signed with a certificate that is trusted, but that's probably your only chance.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/EnableMacros.aspx

Comment: make all the sheets hidden by default and show them once the workbook is loaded (= when the user enables content)

Comment: Tim Williams, your link explains very clear my situation. 
I could adapt some things from that code to my reality and it works.
Thanks a lot, everyone!!!!!